# Reading from a buffer word by word in c

Tags: c, windows, string, char, scanf

I have a Buffer received as a result of recvfrom(). lets say,

> char buffer[12] = "Hello 1";

I want to separate Hello and 1 and store them in different buffers so that one buffer has "Hello" in it and other buffer or an int variable has "1" stored in it.

In other words I want to separate contents of a buffer on the basis of spaces. How can this be done?

I tried:

```
int number;
char buff[7];
sscanf (buffer,"%s %d",buff,number);
```

Will this approach work?

Comment: Be aware of NULL-termination though, the C string functions do expect it, but the socket functions don't write terminating NULLs to the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach works but you need to change to change your `sscanf` to:

```
sscanf (buffer,"%s %d",buff,&number);
```

The %d expects an `int*` and you are sending an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

If there are only 2 words your idea will work. But there is a small error in your code.
Change the sscanf this way

```
sscanf (buffer,"%s %d",buff,&number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), it can do exactly that. But make sure your string is NULL-terminated, `recv` and other socket functions don't do that for you and the standard C string functions do expect NULL-termination.